# Can you change the colour of <legend>?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if you could change the colour of the line that the tag `<legend>` makes?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Well, I don't know how, so I just went ahead and asked

Comment: Also, legends don't have what you call "the line". You should definitely go study this material, if only to get a grasp on the nomenclature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by changing the `border-color` of fieldset tag.

CSS code

```
.fieldset{
   border-color: #ff0000; /*color of your choice*/
}
```

Html code

```
<fieldset style="border-color:#ff0000">
  <legend>Some name:</legend>  
</fieldset>
```